# node template engine rendering for multiple pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, template-engine

I wrote following function for rendering a page. But I have 100's pages should I write same for each and every page?? Is there any easy way please suggest.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
con.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE advisor=1",function (error, result) {
    if(error) throw error;
    res.render('stack/chat',{users:result});
  });
});
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by you have 100's of pages. Are they all totally different? Do they share common HTML code?

Comment: @kessir Yes they are.

Comment: If that's really the case then you have to write that for every page. To be honest, it's quite rare to have that many different pages in an app. There must be some recurring components on all those pages.

Comment: @kessir I handled in a different way  `app.get('/:views', function (req, res) {
  var data={id:2,chatToken:"skldmkld",team:"test"}
  res.render(req.params.views,{data:data});
})`

Comment: Makes perfect sense!